# Node-RED: how to iterate over all nodes in the editor

Tags: node-red

How do I iterate over all nodes in the editor (from within an input element event handler)?

(I want to find a node with a name matching the current input)

Comment: You are going to need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69318197/edit) the question to provide a LOT more detail about what you are trying to achieve here, but under 99.9999999% of circumstances a node REALLY should NOT care where an input came from.

Comment: Well, the background of this question is to implement s.th. like "flow subroutines" with proper editor support - for this I need to be able to introspect the set of nodes and their interconnections

Comment: Sub flows are already a feature of Node-RED

Comment: I do not want subflows as they consume their own tab (and also add themselves to the nodes palette). Handling a lot of  subflows therefore becomes tedious. Additionally, it is not possible to keep multiple related subflows on the same tab (e.g., to form s.th. like a "library" of flows)

Comment: The tabs can be closed and the entry in the Palette is the library...

Comment: but I neither want to spend a full separate tab for a (potentially small) flow nor to pollute the palette with an unstructured list of subflows - instead I prefer s.th. similar (but not equal) to node-red-contrib-components or node-red-contrib-actionflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to not leave this question unanswered:

answers for this question and similar ones (dealing with the internals of Node-RED) may be found in [some postings written by Nick O'Leary for the Node-RED forum](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/how-can-i-set-the-error-indicator-little-red-triangle-of-a-node-in-the-editor/51481/7)

The following is just a copy from there:

**Everything that follows only applies in the editor. This is no equivalent in the runtime.**

#### Finding by name

There's no direct way to find anything by its 'name' - names are optional fields and can be left blank. They are also not unique. Under the covers you should be using the id field to reference other nodes.

```
let node = RED.nodes.node(id);
```

To get any nodes whose name property is set to a particular value:

```
let results = [];
RED.nodes.eachNode(function(node) {
   if (node.name === "HELLO") {
      results.push(node);
   }
});
```

(If you dig around the code, you'll see `RED.nodes.filterNodes` exists - that currently only filters on `z` and `type` rather than any other property... but it would be simply enough to update to handle any property... we have never needed it)

The above works for regular flow nodes. To do the same for Config nodes or Flows, you'd do the same but with `eachConfig()` and `eachWorkspace()` respectively.

##### Find connected nodes of a given node

```
let node = RED.nodes.node(nodeId);
let allConnectedNodes = RED.nodes.getAllFlowNodes(node)
```

If you just want the nodes that come 'before' or 'after' this one, you can do:

```
let allUpstreamNodes = RED.nodes.getAllUpstreamNodes(node);
let getAllDownstreamNodes = RED.nodes.getAllDownstreamNodes(node)
```

Comment: Does `getAllUpstreamNodes` and `getAllDownstreamNodes` get nodes in order, i.e. closest node = `getAllDownstreamNodes[0]`?

Comment: after having looked into the code (file [nodes.js](https://github.com/rozek/node-red/blob/master/packages/node_modules/%40node-red/editor-client/src/js/nodes.js), line 1002 onwards) I have severe doubts that the lists of nodes delivered by `getAllUpstreamNodes` or `getAllDownstreamNodes` are sorted in any way - you _could_ be lucky, but you can't _rely_ on any order

Comment: Agreed, that seems overly complicated as opposed to simply recursing over `node`s out-ports...